# MANIFEST.MF in RAD not listing all dependencies

Tags: rad, dependency-management, websphere-6.1, manifest.mf

In my RAD, when I open up the MANIFEST.MF file for an ejb project, because I need to add dependencies, in the UI, I see (under dependencies):

```
Select other JARs or modules contained by the EAR that are required by this JAR or module.  Only valid or existing dependencies are shown.
```

What does it mean by `Only valid or existing dependencies`. I say this because not all projects in the workspace are listed under Dependencies. And the project that I need to add as dependency is not listed here. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution although do not understand the reason. I need to add the project jar under JAVA EE Module Dependencies